# css sprite as background, limited portion?

Tags: css, image, sprite

I need to place an icon of 48x48 as background. I have this icon in my image sprite where of course there are many other images.

Is there a way to show as background only a porition of the image?

thanks

EDIT: Is there a way to do this without setting width-height of the backgrounded element? (I am not sure if acutally i can set a width-height)

Edit2: this is what i need: http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width and height of the element to 48px.

```
.element{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

Set the background of the element to your image

```
.element{
    background-image: url('image.png');
}
```

Move the background so that the top left corner of the icon is positioned correctly.

```
.element{
    background-position: 20px 94px;
}
```

The two numbers in background-position are the X and Y coordinates (respectively) where the top left corner of your 48px by 48px is in your sprite image.  So maybe it's actually `96px 0px` or something.

### EDIT

If you can't control the width and height of the element you are trying to put the background in, but you can add new DOM elements, you can try adding a span inside the element you really want to put the image as a background for.

It would look something like:

```
<div id="noControl">
    <span id="justCreated">
    </span>
</div>
```

and the CSS would look exactly the same as above, except you would need to treat the inline span as a block element:

```
#justCreated{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### EDIT 2

If you have control over new DOM elements, and want to make your sprite the background without messing with a span, just add another div inside your original one.

Would wind up looking like:

```
<div id="noControl">
    <div id="justCreated">
        ALL of the content that used to be inside #noControl
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS for it would be

```
#justCreated{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url('image.png');
    background-position: 96px 0px;

    z-index: -200;
    /* z-index of all the contents needs to be not set, or set to larger than -200 */
}
```

This is all theoretical, but it SHOULD work.

This way, you can apply the sprite sizing to a block element without messing with the inline stuff.  This may affect CSS if it addresses elements by child status (like `#noControl > a`), because you are inserting a div between the parent and the child.

I am still researching whether you can do this at all if you have no control over the DOM at all.

Comment: @yes123, can you add elements inside the element?  You need something to shrink around your icon that creates a "window" that you can only see the icon you want through.  If you don't have control over **any** DOM elements, you might be SOL.

Comment: I can add elements to DOM that's not a problem. But adding an inline-block how that can be placed as background under the other elments inside the id="noControl" ??

Comment: You'll need to set the z-indices to accommodate the new element.  You can set the z-index of the new span to something very large in the negative direction, and it should fall behind all the other elements.  This may take a lot of fiddling.  I'll update my answer with ANOTHER option, which may make things a little easier.

Comment: rockerest your are earning the Answer tick! xD

Comment: So, the problem with my new update is that it might still have consequences on your CSS (which is why I assume you can't touch the outer container).  It's also possible it won't affect anything, but there's a chance.  If you can't add a div around your content, you'll have to add a span or div as a sibling to the content and position it behind the content as per @Hossein's answer

Comment: rock I don't get how ur last solution css would be =/

Comment: @yes123 I've updated my answer.  You may need to position #justCreated inside #noControl to get it to look correct.

Comment: so my original content should be outside .justCreated?

Comment: It's very difficult to know based on the information you've given.  Can you update your question with the HTML you need to edit?  Mark the parts you can't change.  Maybe even use a service like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to give me an idea of what it should look like.  I'm pretty much shooting in the dark with the info you posted.

Comment: here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/ i have linked the google sprite. I need that but I need to show only a pic from the sprite

Comment: please keep in mind this is an example.. i know i could easly achived that with 2 div with float:left and float:right

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/3/)

Comment: @yes123 I've updated the jsfiddle with a few minor changes.  Nothing important really changed. [http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/4/).  Please update here if this is not what you are looking for, or if it helped you.

Comment: Man take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/ (i already posted this on top) I need to show as background only the "google" logo. But i guess i will need anyway to set another div inside with a prefixed "height" on the left. Anyway i give you the answer even tho you did something I will not use.

Comment: @yes123 please examine this jsfiddle (it's an update of the one you posted): [http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/5/).  Unfortunately, it uses absolute positioning, but I think it does what you want.

Comment: @rock: yes that is much near to what I need. but of course in the page flow i can't rly use position:absolute xD

Comment: @yes123 One final update.  This shows how this can work with absolute positioning.  Because the absolute position is relative to it's parent element, it still stays in the proper spot: [http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/pdxnj/6/).  I'm sure you can figure it out from here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

simple answer no, but by using html elements you can. Html element hight and width should match the background portion of image.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you're not going to be setting a repeating background. Otherwise no.

To do this, you need to play around with the background offset, and width/height of the actual element that you're setting the background on.

Answer (score 0):

it will depend on how much whitespace is around it in the sprite whether it will fit where you need it to without showing parts of other images.. however you could e.g. put a span where you want the image and crop the span to 48x48 so that it only shows the icon itself. it kind of depends what you want to use it for and how the sprite is built

Answer (score 0):

It's better using ::before or ::after so you can easily define your image size without having overflow problems!

Answer (score -1):

This is possible. You need to display that in a 48x48 div then set `position: absolute` style for the div and define `left` and `top` too for it. Also set `z-index: 0` for the div so that it appears under everything.

Comment: Just to clarify why this was probably downvoted (you should really explain your downvotes so the community can improve!):  The user was asking how to sprite an image, and you basically gave an answer saying that he should absolutely position an element behind his desired location.  This doesn't get to the meat of the question at all, since his image has other icons contained in it, and he needs to limit and move the background image, not the element.

Comment: @rockerest: The user was NOT asking how to sprite an image, he already knew that and he wanted to know how to sprite the background of a page. Now I look at your answer, i see that the approach suggested is a bit similar to mine. The div worked as the background here. (Just to clarify my own answer. Don't answer this.)

Comment: In my country, I have freedom of speech, so I'll answer this if I please.  If the user was not asking how to sprite an image, then how do you explain this direct quote from his question? "Is there a way to show as background only a porition of the image?"  In addition, his original jsfiddle he posted did not have the image sprited, if he knew he needed it sprited (he did) and he knew how to do it, why didn't he?  Your answer was half of the answer.  Before any of the updates or comments on my answer, your answer appeared to be completely wrong.  I'm just explaining why it was LIKELY downvoted.